# Does Istio envoy proxy sidecar has anything to do with container filesystem?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, istio

Recently I was adding Istio to my kubernetes cluster. When enabling istio to one of the namespaces where MongoDB statefulset were deployed, MongoDB was failed to start up.

The error message was "keyfile permissions too open"

When I analyzed whats going on, keyfile is coming from the /etc/secrets-volume which is mounted to the statefulset from kubernetes secret.

The file permissions was 440 instead of 400. Because of this MongoDB started to complain that "permissions too open" and the pod went to Crashbackloopoff.

When I disable Istio injection in that namespace, MongoDB is starting fine.

Whats going on here? Does Istio has anything to do with container filesystem, especially default permissions?

Comment: Hi, istio injecting a MongoDB is a very complicated task. Injecting MongoDB that is using statefulset even more so. If You wish to have access for Your services to the MongoDB it is possible to use `ServiceEntry` instead of sidecar injection. Would You be interested in that?

Answer (score 1):

The istio sidecar injection is not always meant for all kinds of containers like mentioned in istio documentation [guide](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/#more-control-adding-exceptions). These containers should be excluded from istio sidecar injection.

In case of Databases that are deployed using `StatefulSets` some of the containers might be temporary or used as operators which can end up in crash loop or other problematic states.

There is also alternative approach to not istio inject databases at all and just add them as external services with `ServiceEntry` objects. There is entire [blog post](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2018/egress-mongo/) in istio documentation how to do that specifically with MongoDB. the guide is little outdated so be sure to refer to current [documentation page](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/) for `ServiceEntry` which also has examples of using external MongoDB.

Hope it helps.

Comment: the documentation is about connecting to mongodb external to cluster. what if mongodb is deployed as stateful set & we need to exclude the side car for mongodb? @piotr